# Read binary from RethinkDb

Tags: c#, rethinkdb

I'm trying to read binary from RethinkDb in C# using RethinkDb.Driver
When I look at it using the data explorer it looks like this:

```
"Content": <binary, 270.7KB, "89 50 4e 47 0d 0a..."> ,
```

But when I try to read it from "Content" I get this:

```
{
  "$reql_type$": "BINARY",
  "data": "iVBORw0KGgo[...]"
}
```

But I'm not sure how to convert this string to C#, I tried different way but everytime I get something different than what it should be.

So my question is, how can I read something stored in binary in Rethinkdb then convert it to a byte[]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I somehow found the answer a bit after posting my question...
I had to use R.binary:

```
(byte[])await _r.Binary(elem["Content"]).RunAsync<byte[]>(_conn);
```